# Trying to isolate bootstrap by using Less

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am following this tutorial https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap I am using Terminal on my Mac. I have done steps 1-3. When I try to do step 4 it says "lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mikelee/prefix.less' ". Can anyone figure out what is going wrong or suggest a better/easier way to isolate bootstrap css? Thanks.

Comment: Please put what commands you ran in your terminal into your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isolated css for Bootstrap 4.1 (compiled with LESS) -

https://github.com/cryptoapi/Isolate-Bootstrap-4.1-CSS-Themes

It have isolated css for themes -

- bootstrapcustom.min.css - default bootstrap 4.1 isolated style
- https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/ darkly.min.css - isolated css
- https://bootswatch.com/darkly/ flatly.min.css - isolated css
- https://bootswatch.com/flatly/ litera.min.css - isolated css
- https://bootswatch.com/litera/ lux.min.css - isolated css
- https://bootswatch.com/lux/ minty.min.css - isolated css
- ...